# How to Add "itemReviewed" in WP-postratings plugin

Tags: wordpress, schema, google-rich-snippets

I want to set up the markup of Reviews on the site that would be in the snippet search engine displayed stars and the author of the review.

CMS site: WordPress 5.3 - Astra theme
I use the plugin: WP-Postrating (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-postratings/)

1.changed the type of markup in function.php using the filter as described in the plugin instructions:

```
 add_filter( 'wp_postratings_schema_itemtype', 'wp_postratings_schema_itemtype' );  
    function wp_postratings_schema_itemtype( $itemtype ) {  
        return 'itemscope itemtype';  
    }
```

Markup is now defined as Review [link](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Fimprovecraft.com%2Fbest-vinyl-cutters%2F%20Test%20page:%20https://improvecraft.com/best-vinyl-cutters/)

But because of the error: It is necessary to specify the value for the `itemReviewed` field.

Stars and the author are not displayed in the snippet of the search system.

Please give us a hint. What code should I add to `function.php` to add this field? And what would you like to see in this field, for example, the title of an article or manually fill in `itemReviewed`. Perhaps you need to add some special field to the article editor.

I would be very grateful. The employer wants to do this, I am a novice developer at https://improvecraft.com/

Answer (score 0):

It's an old question and you probably figured out how to add this code. If someone still needs it, this code should work (and you can change also itemtype):

```
add_filter( 'wp_postratings_schema_itemtype','wp_postratings_schema_itemtype');
function wp_postratings_schema_itemtype($itemtype) {

    global $post;

    $title = get_the_title($post->ID);

    return 'itemscope itemReviewed="' . $title . '" itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness"';
}
```

Comment: Didn't wait for an answer and changed the template on the site to GeneratePress =)
But thanks anyway